# Primefaces DataTable filtering warning

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5, and i have a DataTable component in my form.

When i try to use filters like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) primefaces showcase, I'm getting this warning message:

```
WARNING: DataTable j_idt7:j_idt8:someList has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined, for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue. It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25928) :

> See the user guide on page 133 'Data Filtering' in the chapter
>   dataTable. There is a new attribute filteredValue that should point to
>   a List in a ViewScoped managed bean to store the filtered values the
>   user typed in.